# Check file content SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bcp, fileinfo

We have an interface, which creates three files everyday with following name format:

1. FileAYYYYMMDD  (Example:  FileA20170925)
2. FileBYYYYMMDD  (Example: FileB20170925)
3. FileCYYYYMMDD  (Example:  FileC20170925)

Someone manually needs to check to make sure whether these files are empty or not. I want to automate this step.

What I like to know:
Is there a way to determine via SQL query or SQL job whether these files are empty (Yes or No is good enough)?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/)

Comment: I don't need to read the file.  I just need to know whether three files are empty or not.  Plus everyday file names change because YYYYMMDD attached.

Comment: There was a link in the comments under the question i first linked to. I changed the link now. It should be possible with adjusting the user defined function to your needs. BTW: You clearly wrote Yes or No is good enough. ;-)

Comment: Oh i've seen now that there's also a stored procedure available on the site, called `spFileDetails`. With this you should be able to read the file size and determine if the file is empty or not.

Comment: I can't make your suggestion as an answer!  I was able to look up spFileDetails stored procedure and using this stored procedure, I was able to get file details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the filesize with the stored procedure `spFileDetails` from this [site](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/).

If the filesize is `0` then the file is empty.
Here's a copy of the stored procedure. Thanks to "Phil Factor"

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spFileDetails]    Script Date: 03/28/2007 15:28:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFileDetails]
@Filename VARCHAR(100)

/*
spFileDetails 'c:\autoexec.bat'
*/
AS
DECLARE @hr INT,         --the HRESULT returned from 
       @objFileSystem INT,              --the FileSystem object
       @objFile INT,            --the File object
       @ErrorObject INT,        --the error object
       @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(255),--the potential error message
       @Path VARCHAR(100),--
       @ShortPath VARCHAR(100),
       @Type VARCHAR(100),
       @DateCreated datetime,
       @DateLastAccessed datetime,
       @DateLastModified datetime,
       @Attributes INT,
       @size INT



SET nocount ON

SELECT @hr=0,@errorMessage='opening the file system object '
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject',
                                       @objFileSystem OUT
IF @hr=0 SELECT @errorMessage='accessing the file '''
                                       +@Filename+'''',
       @ErrorObject=@objFileSystem
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @objFileSystem,
         'GetFile',  @objFile out,@Filename
IF @hr=0 
       SELECT @errorMessage='getting the attributes of '''
                                       +@Filename+'''',
       @ErrorObject=@objFile
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'Path', @path OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'ShortPath', @ShortPath OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'Type', @Type OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'DateCreated', @DateCreated OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'DateLastAccessed', @DateLastAccessed OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'DateLastModified', @DateLastModified OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'Attributes', @Attributes OUT
IF @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty 
             @objFile, 'size', @size OUT


IF @hr<>0
       BEGIN
       DECLARE 
               @Source VARCHAR(255),
               @Description VARCHAR(255),
               @Helpfile VARCHAR(255),
               @HelpID INT

       EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @errorObject, 
               @source output,@Description output,
                               @Helpfile output,@HelpID output

       SELECT @ErrorMessage='Error whilst '
                               +@Errormessage+', '
                               +@Description
       RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,16,1)
       END
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objFileSystem
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objFile
SELECT [Path]=  @Path,
       [ShortPath]=    @ShortPath,
       [Type]= @Type,
       [DateCreated]=  @DateCreated ,
       [DateLastAccessed]=     @DateLastAccessed,
       [DateLastModified]=     @DateLastModified,
       [Attributes]=   @Attributes,
       [size]= @size
RETURN @hr
```

Answer (score 1):

Per MatSnow's suggestion, I was able to find/create spFileDetails stored procedure.  Using this stored procedure I was able to create SSRS report which would help me automate the process.  Also, I can even evaluate historical files by passing a date parameter:

```
declare @FileDATE AS VARCHAR(8) 
select @FileDATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ReportDate, 112))

DECLARE @FolderLocation as varchar(200) 
select @FolderLocation =  ( '\\share\\Validation\File' + @FileDATE + '.txt')

DECLARE @FolderLocationA as varchar(200) 
select @FolderLocationA = ( '\\share\\Validation\FileA' + @FileDATE + '.txt')

DECLARE @FolderLocationB as varchar(200) 
select @FolderLocationB = ( '\\share\\Validation\FileB' + @FileDATE + '.txt')


DECLARE @TempTable Table(
[Path] varchar(300),    
ShortPath   varchar(300),
[Type]  varchar(20),
DateCreated  date,
DateLastAccessed date,  
DateLastModified    date,
Attributes  int , 
size int)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
Execute dba.dbo.uspGetFileDetails  @FolderLocation
INSERT INTO @TempTable
Execute dba.dbo.uspGetFileDetails  @FolderLocationA
INSERT INTO @TempTable
Execute dba.dbo.uspGetFileDetails  @FolderLocationB

Select * from @TempTable
```